# How to handle the missing values in newly listed stocks?

Tags: time-series, missing-data, data-imputation, finance

I am trying to test some asset pricing models on 10 portfolios for the period of 2010-2020. The problem is that three of these portfolios included stocks that are newly listed in 2017 and 2018, so I only have three years of historical data for these stocks. Can anyone help how to solve this problem? I don't want to exclude these stocks; does imputation makes sense for such a long period?

Comment: It could help to have more detail about what you mean by "I am trying to test some asset pricing models".

Comment: Imputation of such a large proportion of data points certainly sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for your point of view, appreciated.

Comment: @Adrian I mean that I want to test the performance of CAPM, Fama-French 3F and Fma-French 5F on 10 portfolios belong to different sectors. Does that make sense?  I have the majority of data but some stocks are newly listed, so I don't have their historical data for the whole period. Any idea how to solve this situation?

Comment: I do not think this is solvable. Absense of data is one of the most serious and fundamental obstacles. There *may* be a way, but I do not see it...

Comment: The same on Economics Stack Exchange: [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/43689).

Comment: Thank you so much Richard, I really appreciate your contribution